# Search API for Windows App Store

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a search API for the Windows App Store? I'm looking for anything like the [Apple Search API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be no official API for searching the Windows Marketplace.

[This](http://brandonwatson.sys-con.com/node/1767886) might be helpful, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will use the way you mentioned.